# Reading a local file with Google App Scripts? If not, workarounds?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is it possible to read local files with google app scripts?

If not, are there any workarounds to read local files? I want to develop a script that anyone I share with can use to move excel data around in google sheets the exact way I want them to.

Comment: DON'T use the `script` tag. Every SO question is about scripts one way or another. It's no better than adding `code` as a tag. That tag is just noise, it was deleted in the past and will be deleted very soon again.

Answer (score 3):

You have not really provided anything you have tried so far, so I am making some assumptions here.

First of all you could create a dialog for uploading the file:

```js
// Code.gs

function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .createMenu('Upload Menu')
      .addItem('Show dialog', 'showUploadDialog')
      .addToUi();
}

function showUploadDialog() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Page')
      .setWidth(400)
      .setHeight(300);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
      .showModalDialog(html, 'Upload File');
}
```

Then for the html to show in the dialog

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    Please select a file to upload.
    <input id="fileInput" type="file" />
    <button id="uploadButton" onclick="uploadFile()">Upload</button>

    <script>

      function onSuccess(data){
        alert("Success");
      }
      function onFailure(err){
        alert("Exception " + err );
      }

      function uploadFile(){
        let element = document.getElementById("fileInput");
        let file = element.files[0];
        let name = file.name;
        // Convert the file to base64
        getBase64(file,name);
      }

      
function getBase64(file, fileName) {
   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.readAsDataURL(file);
   reader.onload = function () {
     // The replace function assumes this as excel sheet. Of course a cleaner method would be using regex in case of other types
     let baseFile = reader.result.replace("data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,","");
     // pass the base 64 to the server
       google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(onSuccess)
          .withFailureHandler(onFailure)
          .uploadFile(baseFile, fileName );
   };
}

    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

And finally you need the uploadFile - function on the server side to save the file. Please note that the function that converts the file needs [Advanced Drive Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive) enabled.

```js
function uploadFile(uploadedFile, fileName)
{
  try{
    
    // decode the base64 and convert to  blob
    var decoded = Utilities.base64Decode(uploadedFile);
    var blob = Utilities.newBlob(decoded,MimeType.MICROSOFT_EXCEL, fileName);
    
    // Use this to save the file as excel
    // let folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(yourFolderID);
    // folder.createFile(blob); 

    // Enable the advanced Drive Service to use this function that converts the excel  file to a Google Sheets file
    Drive.Files.insert({title:"sheet"}, blob, {convert: true});
    return "Success";
  }catch(ex)
  {
    Logger.log(ex);
    throw ex;
  }
 
}
```

Now the file has been saved to Drive in Google Sheets - file format, which is readable by Google App Script.

Comment: I apologize. I should have been more clear. I am explicitly looking for reading a file off of my desktop like in pandas when you read a file. You can copy the file path ("/home/user/Documents/file.csv").

I regualrly have to do update files onto my google drive and do not want an avalanche of random files on my main page.
However, Thank you so much for this approach!!

Comment: I understand. Of course in this approach you could save the excel as a temp-file, read it and then delete after it has been read. Also you can define the folder where to save the temp-files, which can keep help you keep your main page organized too.

Comment: Sure you could get the file in the  function uploadFile() like now, but pass it to a function that reads the excel in the client side, then passes the data to the server side.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another simpler approach where you can upload data from a local XLS file using a pop-up prompt within your Google Sheet.

Make sure you assign the script importExcel to a button or a menu option.

Here is a working script:

```
function importExcel(e) {

  if (!e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("uploadExcelpopup"), "Upload PIMMS Excel file");
    return;
  }

  var file = Utilities.newBlob(...e);

  let config = {
    title: "[Temporary Google Sheet] " + file.getName(),
    mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS
  };
  let tempSs = Drive.Files.insert(config, file);

  var 
  fileId = tempSs.id,
  source = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId),
  sourceSheet = source.getSheets()[0];

    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('Extracting data',' File uploaded',10);

  var
  sourceValues = sourceSheet.getRange(1,1,sourceSheet.getLastRow(),sourceSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues(),
  sheetDataset = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dataset");

  sheetDataset.getRange(1, 1, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length).setValues(sourceValues);

  DriveApp.getFileById(fileId).setTrashed(true);

    SpreadsheetApp.getActive().toast('', '✔️ Upload complete',10);
    
}
```

You will also need to create an HTML file:

```
<form>
  <input type="file" name="file" onchange="importExcel(this.parentNode)" accept=".xls,.xlsx,.xlsm" id="inputFile" >
  <font face = "Calibri" size = "3"> <br><div id="progress">⏳ Waiting</div></font>
</form>
<script>
function importExcel(e) {
  const div = document.getElementById("progress");
  div.innerHTML = " Uploading";
  const file = e.file.files[0];
  const f = new FileReader();
  f.onload = d => google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(_ => {
    div.innerHTML = "✔️ Done";
    setTimeout(google.script.host.close, 1000);
  }).importExcel([[...new Int8Array(d.target.result)], file.type, file.name]);
  f.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
  
}
</script>
```

You can specify for data to sit below any data previously imported:

```
sheetDataset.getRange(sheetDataset.getLastRow()+1, 1, sourceValues.length, sourceValues[0].length).setValues(sourceValues);
```

I also suggest you include a dataset cleaning process on before pasting the imported data, if you want to replace any previous data available:

```
sheetDataset.getRange(1,1,sheetDataset.getLastRow(),sheetDataset.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
```

or

```
  try { sheetDataset.deleteRows(4, sheetDataset.getMaxRows()-3); } catch(e) {}
```

This is based on [Tanaike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7108653/tanaike)'s CSV local input pop-up suggestion:

[Google Sheets Import CSV popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71303500/google-sheets-import-csv-popup)

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since this question was asked, now I had the same wish.
I came up a workaround that might be helpfull for others.
Here it is:

1. Install Google Drive on your PC/Mac: https://www.google.com/drive/download/
2. In Preferences of that Drive application: add the map containing the file you want the script to read
3. In your script: Access the file on your Drive with `DriveApp.get...` or else

Still working on how to get the content properly under control, BUT: I have it in my script now!