# Parse CSV number as text

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to import the following CSV data into a Google Sheet, preserving the number format "0001,0002,0003" as a string.

**CSV file**

```
0001,0002,0003
test,test2,test3
```

I tried using Tanaike's code:

[Google Sheets Import CSV popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71303500/google-sheets-import-csv-popup)

```
function importCsv(e){
  if (!e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index"), "sample");
    return;
  }
  const csv = Utilities.parseCsv(Utilities.newBlob(...e).getDataAsString());
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setValues(csv);
}
```

But also the Batch Update one:
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/batchUpdate

```
function importCsvbatchUpdate(e){
  
    if (!e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index"), "sample");
    return;
    }

var data = Utilities.parseCsv(Utilities.newBlob(...e).getContentText());

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();


var resource = {
  requests: [
    {
      pasteData: {
        data: data,
        coordinate: { sheetId: sheet.getSheetId() },
        delimiter: ","
      }
    }
  ]
};
Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, ss.getId());
```

Both work as expected, but unfortunately, the "0001,0002,0003" in the CSV files are systematically populated as numbers "1,2,3" in Google Sheets.

Any ideas on how to keep the text/string formats of values with prefixed zeros?

Comment: Use `console.log(data);` , `console.log(csv)`, etc... to find at what point the string looses the "000"s. If you find that point, you could try `.padStart()`, `.split()`, and `.join()`.

Comment: I reopened the question because in this case the op does not have the data in a form from which Tanaikes code could collect the data formats.  I believe they are just looking for a way to preserve the data in this form `0001,0002,0003`.  I don't use numberformats all that much so I don't  know much about them and I can't help but closing the questioin is definitely not going to help the op.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```
function importCsv(e){
  if (!e) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index"), "sample");
    return;
  }
  const csv = Utilities.parseCsv(Utilities.newBlob(...e).getDataAsString());
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setNumberFormat("@").setValues(csv); // Modified
}
```

- By this modification, the values are put into cells as strings. By this, `0001` is put as `0001`.

#### Note:

- From `as I understand it each element of the csv comes in the form of triplets like this "0001,0002,0003"` in [the Cooper's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76955118/parse-csv-number-as-text/76957515?noredirect=1#comment135666322_76957515), when I saw this question, I guessed that from `Both work as expected, but unfortunately, the "0001,0002,0003" in the CSV files are systematically populated as numbers "1,2,3" in Google Sheets.` and the sample CSV data, `0001`,`0002`, and `0003` might be each cell. When `"0001,0002,0003"` is included in the CSV data, I think that `0001,0002,0003` will be put into a cell. But, if `"0001,0002,0003"` is included in your CSV data, please test the following modification. In this case, I think that both patterns can be used.

  ```js
  function importCsv(e) {
    if (!e) {
      SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile("index"), "sample");
      return;
    }

    const temp1 = Utilities.parseCsv(Utilities.newBlob(...e).getDataAsString()).map(r => r.flatMap(c => c.split(",")));
    const maxLen = Math.max(...temp1.map((r) => r.length));
    const csv = temp1.map((r) => [...r, ...Array(maxLen - r.length).fill(null)]);

    const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, csv.length, csv[0].length).setNumberFormat("@").setValues(csv);
  }
  ```

#### Reference:

- [setNumberFormat(numberFormat)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setnumberformatnumberformat)

Comment: as I understand it each element of the csv comes in the form of triplets like this "0001,0002,0003"

Comment: @Cooper Thank you for replying. About your comment, I added one more sample script. Please confirm it. If I misunderstood your comment, I apologize.

Comment: I think that is a correct solution

Answer (score 0):

Please select Tanaike's solution I that I had tried "@" but I guess I not.  Any way this is my simplistic approach to testing and it seems to work.

```
function myfunk() {
  let csv = '"0001,0002,0003","0004,0005,0006","0007,0008,0009"\n"0001,0002,0003","0004,0005,0006","0007,0008,0009"\n"0001,0002,0003","0004,0005,0006","0007,0008,0009"\n"0001,0002,0003","0004,0005,0006","0007,0008,0009"\n"0001,0002,0003","0004,0005,0006","0007,0008,0009"\n"0001,0002,0003","0004,0005,0006","0007,0008,0009"\n"0001,0002,0003","0004,0005,0006","0007,0008,0009"\n';
  let arr = Utilities.parseCsv(csv, ",");
  Logger.log(JSON.stringify(arr));
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  sh.getRange(1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setNumberFormat("@").setValues(arr);
}
```

And this is what I got

|  | A | B | C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0001,0002,0003 | 0004,0005,0006 | 0007,0008,0009 |
| 2 | 0001,0002,0003 | 0004,0005,0006 | 0007,0008,0009 |
| 3 | 0001,0002,0003 | 0004,0005,0006 | 0007,0008,0009 |
| 4 | 0001,0002,0003 | 0004,0005,0006 | 0007,0008,0009 |
| 5 | 0001,0002,0003 | 0004,0005,0006 | 0007,0008,0009 |
| 6 | 0001,0002,0003 | 0004,0005,0006 | 0007,0008,0009 |
| 7 | 0001,0002,0003 | 0004,0005,0006 | 0007,0008,0009 |

So hopefully this will assist the op if not I'm sorry.

Comment: About `Please select Tanaike's solution I that I had tried "@" but I guess I not.`, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating it? I would like to confirm it. If you can cooperate to resolve your issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: I thought I had tried that format but when I tried after you provided a solution it worked just fine.  So I must have been wrong.

Comment: Thank you for replying and testing it again. I understood it.